# Select field doesn't shows the default value in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

The selectField in my typescript doesn't shows the default value, when I run the server. I need "select" (the default value) whenever I run the server.
In my code the line "option value="none" selected " doesn't work.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="label label-default" for="tour-type">Tournament Type</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="TournamentType" [(ngModel)]="tourDetails.TournamentType">
        <option value="none" selected>Select</option>
        <option value="PSA">PSA</option>
        <option value="NationalCircuit">National Circuit</option>
        <option value="StateClosed">State Closed</option>
        <option value="Asian&World">Asian & World</option>
        <option value="International">International</option>
        <option value="NonRanking">Non-Ranking</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your controller code?

Comment: It doesn't have any controller code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `tourDetails.TournamentType` to `none` in ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit()
    this.tourDetails.TournamentType ="none"
}
```

Comment: `this.tourDetails`

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept this answer if this helped

Answer (score 0):

`tourDetails.TournamentType` needs to be equal to "none" so that it gets selected automatically.

otherwise you can do the following

```
<option value="" selected>Select</option>
```